# How to write a Google Script that auto updates the Filter Range for personal filters

Tags: google-apps-script, dynamic, filter, google-sheets

I have a very large sheet that has multiple tabs for multiple teams, each of these tabs has personalized filter's for each individual & all of these are currently updated regularly and manually as new line items are added to the sheet. How can I write up a Google Script that recognizes the last row with data (ANY) in it, and the last column--then extends the range from A1 to the new end cell and updates each of the filter ranges on this worksheet to this?

Most of the sample code that I have used for this just creates a new filter view for the new range and deletes the previous - but I have between 5 and 20 personal filters on each worksheet that I would like to get updated on a regular basis.
***Edit*** I've provided sample code that I wrote for this, this is not copied but rather using what the UpdateFilterView Request documentation had available. I do not know if I have the filter field set up correctly referencing "filterSettings", and did not know what to use in the "fields" section. Additionally, I cannot tell if the batchUpdate was set up correctly.

**EDIT #2 7.24.2019** - Current code is setup as seen below, getting an invalid JSON payload error currently that says

```
API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "fields" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.
Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_filter_view.filter.filter_view_id' (TYPE_INT32), "*" Invalid JSON payload received. 
Unknown name "sheet_id" at 'requests[0].update_filter_view.filter.range': Cannot find field. (line 27, file "macros")
```

```
function UpdateFilterView() {
    var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();  
    for each (var dataSheet in sheets){ 
      var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
      var sheetId = dataSheet.getSheetId();
      var filterSettings = {
        "filterViewId": "*",
        "range":{
        "sheetID": sheetId,
        "startRowIndex": 0,
        "endRowIndex": lastRow,
        "startColumnIndex": 0,
        "endColumnIndex": lastColumn
        }
       }
      };


var requests = [{
  "fields": "*",
  "updateFilterView":{
  "filter": filterSettings
  }
 }];

 Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests":requests},sheetId);

 }
```

I expect that each personalized filter will update OnEdit() for each of the personalized filters on each worksheet.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Do you have any code already?

Comment: @ross added some sample code to this, its horrendous - but thank you for taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are getting the last row and column of a specific sheet called
>   `dataSheet` (which is not defined in your code btw) instead of doing
>   it for each sheet of interest.

### Instead you need to loop through all sheets and update your filter for each of sheet accessing its range inside the loop:

```js
  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();  
  for each (var dataSheet in sheets){ 
    var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
    var sheetId = dataSheet.getSheetId();
    var filterSettings = {
...
```

Also, keep in mind that the correct syntax is `getSheetId()` and not `getSheetID()`, just as the key word in  `filterSettings` is `"sheetId"` and not `"sheetID"`. You also need to specify `"filterViewId"` in `filterSettings` and `"fields"` in `"updateFilterView"` (can be set to `"*"`).

Comment: Thank you so much! This has gotten me much further, and your notes about the syntax is incredibly appreciated - I only code in VBA/Scripts on rare occasions and random capitalized letters are a shortcoming of mine. 

That said, I have made edits but I am getting a "invalid JSON payload received"

Unknown name "filter_view_id" at 'requests[0].update_filter_view.filter.range: Cannot find field
Unknown name "sheet_id" at requests[0].update_filter_view.filter.range': Cannot find field.

This line in my code is
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests":requests},sheetId);

Comment: Glad it helped! As mentioned above, please replace  "sheetID" in the JSON request by  "sheetId". Apps Script error messages are not always easy to interpret - even if you get the error only in line 27, it can be (and is in this case) originated by the request syntax above.