# Update Google Sheet "Filter View" w/ New Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dynamic, filter, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet with various filter views set in place. Normally this works great but occasionally new rows are added and I have to manually update the range in each filter view. I've tried searching for solutions online and came up with the following code that might update the range:

```js
function UpdateFilterView() {
    var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
    //for each (var dataSheet in sheets){ 
      var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
      var sheetId = dataSheet.getSheetId();
      var filterSettings = {
        "filterViewId": "319575141",
        "range":{
        "sheetId": sheetId,
        "startRowIndex": 1,
        "endRowIndex": lastRow,
        "startColumnIndex": 1,
        "endColumnIndex": lastColumn
        }
       //}
      };


var requests = [{
  "fields": "*",
  "updateFilterView":{
  "filter": filterSettings
  }
 }];
 
  
 Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests":requests},sheetId);

 }
```

I took most of the code from a post I found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170590/how-to-write-a-google-script-that-auto-updates-the-filter-range-for-personal-fil?answertab=votes#tab-top)) but for some reason it won't update the specified filter. Am I missing something? Also, I get the following error when I run the code "ReferenceError: Sheets is not defined (line 32, file "Code")" of which is referencing the line "Sheets.Spreadsheets.....".

Any thoughts on if this is even possible?

Comment: From your error message, I thought that Sheets API might not be enabled. So can you confirm whether Sheets API has already been enabled at Advanced Google services? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) If it is not enabled, please enable it and test it again.

Comment: Is your question resolved after enabling the Sheets API?

Comment: Silly me, I guess I definitely needed to turn on Sheets API. SO I ran the script and received the following error:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload

Any thoughts? @Tanaike

Comment: @Cooper, I get the following error message:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload

Any thoughts?

Comment: More Specifically:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "fields" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field. (line 31, file "Code")

Comment: Thank you for replying. For your new issue, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your replying, I could confirm that in your current situation, Sheets API was enabled at Advanced Google services. By this, I could confirm your error message was changed. In order to resolve the new issue, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Please modify `sheetId` of `Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests":requests},sheetId);` to the spreadsheet ID.
- Please include `"fields": "*"` in the object of `updateFilterView`.

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function UpdateFilterView() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Added
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');  // Modified
  var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheetId = dataSheet.getSheetId();
  var filterSettings = {
    "filterViewId": "319575141",
    "range":{
      "sheetId": sheetId,
      "startRowIndex": 1,
      "endRowIndex": lastRow,
      "startColumnIndex": 1,
      "endColumnIndex": lastColumn
    }
  };
  var requests = [{
    "updateFilterView":{
      "filter": filterSettings,
      "fields": "*",  // Modified
    }
  }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests":requests}, ss.getId());  // Modified
}
```

#### Note:

- When `filterViewId` of `319575141` is not correct, an error like `Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_filter_view.filter.filter_view_id` occurs. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateFilterViewRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatefilterviewrequest)

Comment: You are a GENUIS! That did exactly what I wanted it to do, thank you SO MUCH! You won't believe how much my head has hurt the last few days trying to figure this out.

Comment: @JPadilla_1990 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.