# Script to Update Multiple Filter View Ranges for all sheets in workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Script to Update Multiple Google Sheet Filter View Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346131/script-to-update-multiple-google-sheet-filter-view-ranges) Similar but different question here.

I have several sheets in the same workbook where I would want to set up a trigger for the ranges to update in all of the filterviews for each sheet.

Is my best solution to make a file for each sheet in the workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modified script? In this modification, I modified the sample script at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64348807/7108653).

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). And, please set the sheet names you want to update.

```js
function UpdateFilterView() {
  var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet3",,,];  // Please set the sheet names you want to update.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  var sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { ranges: sheetNames, fields: "sheets(filterViews)" }).sheets;
  var requests = sheets.flatMap((s, i) => {
    var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    var endRowIndex = dataSheet.getLastRow();
    var endColumnIndex = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
    var sheetId = dataSheet.getSheetId();
    return s.filterViews.map(({ filterViewId }) => ({ updateFilterView: { filter: { filterViewId, range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 0, endRowIndex, startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex } }, fields: "*" } }));
  });
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

- When this script is run, all filter views from the specific sheets in a Google Spreadsheet are updated. In this case, one API is used.

#### Note:

- For example, when you want to reflect this script in all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet, you can also the following sample script.

  ```
    function sample() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
      var sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { fields: "sheets(filterViews)" }).sheets;
      var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
      var requests = sheets.flatMap((s, i) => {
        var dataSheet = allSheets[i];
        var endRowIndex = dataSheet.getLastRow();
        var endColumnIndex = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
        var sheetId = dataSheet.getSheetId();
        return s.filterViews ? s.filterViews.map(({ filterViewId }) => ({ updateFilterView: { filter: { filterViewId, range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 0, endRowIndex, startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex } }, fields: "*" } })) : [];
      });
      if (requests.length == 0) return;
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, spreadsheetId);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Comment: The only thing I could think of would be to have all the sheet names pulled programmatically using var sheetNames = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets() 

Thank you so much for this update to your solution from last year!

Comment: @NomadicPeach Thank you for replying. About your reply, I added one more sample script for reflecting the script in all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet. Could you please confirm it?