# Update all filter view ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a app script I can run that will update the ranges of all the filter views on a sheet at once?
I have hundreds of filter views, and it would be laborious to do it manually.

The filter views are all on a sheet called "Data'. I need to change the range from A1:AB3116 TO A1:AB9011

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script to Update Multiple Google Sheet Filter View Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346131/script-to-update-multiple-google-sheet-filter-view-ranges)

Comment: I'm afraid not. Not quite sure how to incorporate the range change that I need into that script?

Comment: You can specify your desired range in the `range` field in the `updateFilterView` requests.  You can indicate the start/end row index and start/end column index. You can visit this links for the full details on the request. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatefilterviewrequest https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#filterview

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, I posted an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change the range of filter views.
- You want to change from "A1:AB3116" to "A1:AB9011" of all filter views in "data" sheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and [enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services), and save the script.

Please confirm `sheetName` and `obj`. In this sample, your provided information is used.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "data"; // This is from your question.
  var obj = [{ before: "A1:AB3116", after: "A1:AB9011" }]; // This is from your question.

  // Retrieve spreadsheet and sheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();

  // Convert a1Notation to gridRange.
  var o = obj.map(({ before, after }) =>
    [before, after].map(r => {
      var rng = sheet.getRange(r);
      var rowStart = rng.getRow() - 1;
      var rowEnd = rowStart + rng.getNumRows();
      var colStart = rng.getColumn() - 1;
      var colEnd = colStart + rng.getNumColumns();
      return { sheetId, startRowIndex: rowStart, endRowIndex: rowEnd, startColumnIndex: colStart, endColumnIndex: colEnd };
    })
  );

  // Create request body for using the batchUpdate of Sheets API.
  var filterViews = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { ranges: [sheetName], fields: "sheets(filterViews)" }).sheets[0].filterViews;
  var requests = filterViews.reduce((ar, { range, ...e }) => {
    var check = o.find(([{ startRowIndex, endRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endColumnIndex }]) => range.startRowIndex == startRowIndex && range.endRowIndex == endRowIndex && range.startColumnIndex == startColumnIndex && range.endColumnIndex == endColumnIndex);
    if (check) {
      ar.push({ updateFilterView: { filter: { filterViewId: e.filterViewId, range: check[1] }, fields: "*" } });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Reuest Sheets API using the created request body.
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the filter views are retrieved from "data" sheet. And, the range of `A1:AB3116` is searched from the retrieved filter views, and when it is found, the range is changed to `A1:AB9011` and update the filter views.
- In this sample, when you change multiple changes of ranges, you can use them in `obj`.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- Related thread

  - [Script to Update Multiple Google Sheet Filter View Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64346131)