# Google Apps Script refresh filter view along with a basic filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I use the following function to refresh basic filters (filtering and sorting) after my data changes:

```
function refreshDashboardFilter() {
  let {
    basicFilter
  } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetID, {
    ranges: ["Dashboard"],
    fields: "sheets(basicFilter)"
  }).sheets[0];

  if (basicFilter) {
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
      requests: [{
        setBasicFilter: {
          filter: basicFilter
        }
      }]
    }, spreadsheetID);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to refresh a filter view as well in a similar way?
Probably, use the same function for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another approach, in order to refresh both the basic filter and the filter view, I think that it can be achieved by 2 API calls. The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function refreshDashboardFilter() {
  const spreadsheetID = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  const sheetNames = ["Dashboard"]; // Please set your sheet names. In this case, you can set multiple sheet names.

  // Retrieve all basicFilters and filterViews from sheets by Sheets API.
  const obj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetID, { ranges: sheetNames, fields: "sheets(basicFilter,filterViews)" });

  // Create a request body.
  const requests = obj.sheets.reduce((ar, { basicFilter, filterViews }) => {
    if (basicFilter) {
      ar.push({ setBasicFilter: { filter: basicFilter } })
    }
    if (filterViews) {
      ar.push(filterViews.map(filter => ({ updateFilterView: { filter, fields: "*" } })));
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  
  // Update all basicFilters and filterViews by Sheets API.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, spreadsheetID);
}
```

- When this script is run, all basicFilters and filterViews of `sheetNames` are refreshed by 2 API calls.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- Related threads.

  - [Update all filter view ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75441068)
  - [How to refresh a sorting with Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77934579)

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion: call `batchUpdate()` with an `updateFilterView` request

You can use another `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get()` method to retrieve the filter views then another `batchUpdate()` to refresh each and every filter view that was retrieved. Each filter view has a unique ID so a separate `batchUpdate()` request is needed for each one.

Try this slightly modified version of your code:

```
function refreshDashboardFilter() {
  let {
    basicFilter
  } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetID, {
    ranges: ["Dashboard"],
    fields: "sheets(basicFilter)"
  }).sheets[0];

  //Retrieves all filter views in the sheet
  let {
    filterViews
  } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetID, {
    ranges: ["Dashboard"],
    fields: "sheets(filterViews)"
  }).sheets[0];

  if (basicFilter) {
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
      requests: [{
        setBasicFilter: {
          filter: basicFilter
        }
      }]
    }, spreadsheetID);
  }

  //Updates all fields of each filter view that was retrieved.
  if (filterViews) {
    filterViews.forEach(filterView => {
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        requests: [{
          updateFilterView: {
            filter: filterView,
            fields: "*"
          }
        }]
      }, spreadsheetID);
    })
  }
}
```

### Reference:

- [updateFilterViewRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatefilterviewrequest)