# How to duplicate a Google Sheets filter view using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This should be an easy question, and yet I can't find any examples online. ([This](https://yagisanatode.com/duplicate-filter-views-in-selected-google-sheet-tabs-with-google-apps-script/#duplicateFilterViewsgs) is much more complicated than what I need.)

**Situation:** I have a spreadsheet with two tabs. One is called "MAIN" and the other is called "NEW". The spreadsheet called "MAIN" has a bunch of filter views. I want to use a script which, when called, copies the filter views of MAIN onto NEW (while also deleting any preexisting filter views on NEW).

**My attempt:**

```
function resetFilterViews(){

  // locate files
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MAIN");
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("NEW");

  // remove existing filter views from NEW
  dest.getFilter().remove();

  // copy all filter views from MAIN onto NEW
  dest.DuplicateFilterViewRequest(source.getFilter());
  
}
```

I can't figure out why `dest.getFilter().remove()` doesn't remove the filters on MAIN. And I'm definitely not using `DuplicateFilterViewRequest` in the correct way (see [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters#manage-filter-views)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several filters in Google Spreadsheet. For example, `getFilter()` can be used for the basic filter. I think that this might be an answer to `I can't figure out why dest.getFilter().remove() doesn't remove the filters on MAIN.`.

In the case of `How to duplicate a Google Sheets filter view using Google Apps Script?`, when `filter view` you think is the filter view, unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the filter views cannot be managed by Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp). So, in this case, it is required to use Sheets API. I guessed that in this case, [this sample script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64348807) might be able to be used. In this answer, I would like to propose a sample script by modifying that sample script.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "MAIN"; // This is from your question.
  const dstSheetName = "NEW"; // This is from your question.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dstSheetId = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName).getSheetId();
  const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { ranges: [srcSheetName, dstSheetName], fields: "sheets(filterViews)" }).sheets;
  const dstFilterViews = dstSheet.filterViews ? dstSheet.filterViews.map(({ filterViewId }) => ({ deleteFilterView: { filterId: filterViewId } })) : [];
  const requests = [
    ...dstFilterViews,
    ...srcSheet.filterViews.map(filter => {
      filter.range.sheetId = dstSheetId;
      delete filter.filterViewId;
      return { addFilterView: { filter } };
    })
  ];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

- When this script is run, all filter views of "MAIN" sheet are copied to "NEW" sheet.
- Added: I include the following function.

  > I would like to delete the filter views in "NEW" (and then add to it the filter views in "MAIN"). Right now, the code adds the ones in "MAIN" to "NEW", but without removing the old filter views from "NEW".

#### Note:

- From `Can you keep your original answer visible as well? That way there are two versions: one that deletes the old filter views, and one that keep them?`, my 1st proposed script is as follows. In this case, the filter views are copied from "MAIN" sheet to "NEW" sheet without removing the filter views of "NEW" sheet.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    const srcSheetName = "MAIN"; // This is from your question.
    const dstSheetName = "NEW"; // This is from your question.

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const dstSheetId = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName).getSheetId();
    var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
    var filterViews = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { ranges: [srcSheetName], fields: "sheets(filterViews)" }).sheets[0].filterViews;
    var requests = filterViews.map(filter => {
      filter.range.sheetId = dstSheetId;
      delete filter.filterViewId;
      return { addFilterView: { filter } };
    });
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, spreadsheetId);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AddFilterViewRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addfilterviewrequest)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike!! This is working, except for the part about deleting the previous filter views.  I'm still confused about that part. How do I delete the previous filter views? `dstSheetId.getFilter().remove();` does not work.

Comment: @Doubt Thank you for replying. About `How do I delete the previous filter views?`, I forgot it. I apologize for this. About `How do I delete the previous filter views?`, in this case, which do you want to delete the filter views in the sheet of "MAIN" or the sheet of "NEW"?

Comment: I would like to delete the filter views in "NEW" (and then add to it the filter views in "MAIN"). Right now, the code adds the ones in "MAIN" to "NEW", but without removing the old filter views from "NEW". Thanks a bunch! @Tanaike

Comment: @Doubt It's ok. I added it in the Note section.

Comment: Thank you so much!! One last question, which really has me stumped. When I switch the text "MAIN" with the text "NEW", it doesn't perform the expected result. This is very surprising, since it seems that the code should be able to handle this. But when I swap "MAIN" with "NEW", instead of copying the filters from "NEW" onto "MAIN", it simply duplicates all the filters on "MAIN". Why would it be doing that?

Comment: @Doubt About `One last question`, I would like to support you. But, the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Absolutely, I have done so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76454824/duplicating-a-google-sheets-filter-view-with-google-apps-script-reversing-direc I'm really stumped by this one