# How to employ Google Sheets API without granting broad authorization? (Google Apps Script)

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534801/google-spreadsheet-api-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes) about authentication scopes with Google Sheets API.

I'm creating a container-bound Script for Google Sheets which makes use of the **Google Sheets API** service (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452523/how-to-duplicate-a-google-sheets-filter-view-using-google-apps-script/76452855#76452855)). The problem is that the Google Sheets API requires the appsscript.jsson file to include:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
```

But this means that the Script has access to **all** of the user's files, whereas it would be much better if I had only:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"]
```

The less authorization the user has to grant, the better. Is there any way to use Google Sheets API without granting such broad authorization?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for example, is `@OnlyCurrentDoc` useful for your situation? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#manual_authorization_scopes_forand) But, I'm not sure whether this is your expected result. So, I posted it as a comment. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike `@OnlyCurrentDoc` cannot be used when Sheets API is active. If used, an error is thrown about `insufficient authentication scopes`. But yes, I'd like to find someway that restricts the authorization to just this current spreadsheet (in a way compatible with Sheets API).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. I would like to study more.